# Does curl command support native characters parameters?

Tags: curl, utf-8, character-encoding

The native characters in PUT, POST methods displayed well, but garbled in GET, HEAD method.

For example:

When I use the curl PUT command:

```
curl -v -X PUT -H "X-Auth-Token: AUTH_tkc0e90e5f298b829cfa16552ec01acb70" http://cnoralcetrial43406.pool1.opcstorage.com:8020/v1/storagetrial2415-cnoralcetrial43406/Container壽喜燒
```

There is no problem in its trace.

But when I use curl GET command to get the list of it, I found they are garbled.
Curl put command:

```
curl -v -X GET -H "X-Auth-Token: AUTH_tkc0e90e5f298b829cfa16552ec01acb70" http://cnoralcetrial43406.pool1.opcstorage.com:8020/v1/storagetrial2415-cnoralcetrial43406
```

And the result is like below, you can see they are garbled.

So I wonder if curl command support native characters parameters?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Your terminal window suggests your terminal character encoding is "big 5", not UTF-8. Are you sure, your terminal encoding and locale match?

Comment: Try having curl save the output to a file instead of the terminal, and then open that file in a text editor that supports UTF-8, and then you can see if the output is what you are expecting.

Comment: @ Alastair McCormack, yes I am sure my terminal encoding and locale match, my terminal locale is also zh_TW.big5. That is my native locale. I want to verify if curl support native characters.